# ¿Cómo muestro cantidad de productos tomados de stocks diferentes?

Tags: php, array

Me encuentro realizando una función en la cual quiero que se ejecute de la siguinete manera:

(Es un ejemplo a grandes razgos y simplificado)

Quiero 7 productos, pero de diferentes stocks, si la existencia es menor a la cantidad, se resta la existencia de la cantidad, pero si el stock es mayor a la cantidad, mostrar solo la cantidad tomada del stock.

En el ejemplo el resultado que muestra es el siguiente:

> 5,  =>(7-2 = 5)

> 5   =>(la existencia es mayor (6),no hace operación porque daría -1, **aquí mi problema**)

> 4, => (5-1= 4)

> no hay suficiente stock   =>(si en dado caso los stocks no cubren la demanda, muestra este mensaje)

Aquí el código de ejemplo:

```
<?php

  $cant = 7;
  $stocks= [2,6,1];

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($stocks); $i++) {

    if ($stocks[$i] >= $cant) {
      echo $cant."<br>";
    }

    if($stocks[$i] <= $cant){
     $cant = $cant - $stocks[$i];
     echo $cant.",<br>";
    }
  }

 if($cant > 0){
   echo "no hay suficiente stock";
 }

?>
```

Lo que busco es saber cómo imprimir la cantidad que se va a tomar de cierto stock cuando éste sea mayor que la cantidad solicitada. Y que el resultado sea el siguente:

> 2 (los 2 que se tomaron del stock 2)

> 5 (los 5 que se tomaron del stock 6)

En este caso ya no se muestra el mensaje de "no hay suficiente stock", porque con el segundo stock le bastó para completar los 7.

Pero no tengo idea de cómo realizar esa función, ya que si hago la resta dentro del stock 6, me daría como resultado `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma (yo creé una función `consumirProductos($cantidad, $stocks)`):

- Si la cantidad es menor o igual que el stock, muestras la cantidad consumida, la seteas en 0 y sales del bucle.
- Si la cantidad es mayor al stock, entonces muestas el stock consumido y disminuyes la cantidad en función de dicho stock.

```
<?php

function consumirProductos($cantidad, $stocks) {
    foreach($stocks as $stock) {
        if($cantidad <= $stock) {
            echo "Se consumieron {$cantidad} unidades. <br/>";
            $cantidad = 0;
            break;
        } else {
            echo "Se consumieron {$stock} unidades. <br/>";
            $cantidad -= $stock;
        }
    }

    if($cantidad > 0) {
        echo "No hay suficiente stock, faltaron {$cantidad} unidades. <br/>";
    }
}

consumirProductos(7, [2,6,1]);

?>
```